# Scanner hasNext(String pattern) falsely returns true

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I have written a scanner utility for parsing a template.
Consider the code snippet :

```
String input = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("input file path"));

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

System.out.println("Checking");
while(scanner.hasNext())
{
    System.out.print(scanner.hasNext("\\s*#[^\\n]*"));
    System.out.println(" : " + scanner.nextLine());
}
```

Input File Contents :

```
# Line 1
#######################

# Check
 # Matched with spaces
     #


// End of file
```

Note : The end of file line is not present in the input.

Output produced :

```
Checking
true : # Line 1
true : #######################
true : 
true : # Check
true :  # Matched with spaces
true :       #
false :      
false :
```

My question is why is it for the third line hasNext() returns true even when it does not start with a '#' ?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Because [`hasNext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> Returns true if the next token matches the pattern constructed from the specified string.

The blank line contains no tokens so it is finding the next token from line 4.

Comment: As read in the doc for hasNext(Pattern): "Returns true if the next complete token matches the specified pattern. A complete token is prefixed and postfixed by input that matches the delimiter pattern." My delimiter is new line char, hence the complete token here should be "" i.e. empty line. Am I wrong here ?

Comment: A little, the delimiter pattern they are referring to is `\\s` whitespace. `hasNext` doesn't know about your pattern.

Comment: In my code I changed the delimiter to new line scanner.useDelimiter(System.getProperty("line.separator")). hasNext operates on a complete token. Also as stated in the docs "The delimiting pattern "\\s" could return empty tokens since it only passes one space at a time.". Hence I was assuming it would return empty token on which hasNext would operate. Correct ?

Comment: I see, maybe you should `scanner.useDelimiter("\\n")` as it is expecting a regex. Or `scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.Quote(System.getProperty("line.separator")));`

Comment: The correct Regular Expression is "\\\r?\\\n"
backslash is a special character in java, and in regular expression syntax, so it needs to be double escaped.

Comment: @Zip158 I have double escaped it, you've tripple escaped it.

Comment: @weston I still have the same issue even after using Pattern.quote ... :(